# Meteor 1.2 Failed to find ANDROID_HOME

Tags: android, linux, meteor

Problem: Meteor cannot find my Android SDK when I try to `meteor add-platform android` on Linux Mint.

I've set my PATH variable: (`echo $PATH`)

```
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jimmy/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/jimmy/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

I've got my ANDROID_HOME variable: (`echo $ANDROID_HOME`)

```
/home/jimmy/Android/Sdk
```

But still, when I run `sudo meteor add-platform android --verbose` I get:

```
Adding platform Android to Cordova project    
% Adding android project...                   
android: added platform                       
Checking Cordova requirements for platform Android

Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for
Android.

Please follow the installation instructions here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Linux

Status of the requirements:                   
✓ Java JDK                                    
✗ Android SDK: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
  setting it manually.
  Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to
  include path to valid SDK directory.
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
  is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Could not find
  Android SDK directory.
  Might need to install Android SDK or set up 'ANDROID_HOME' env variable.
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: because Meteor doesn't like it when I don't use sudo

Comment: Same thing happening to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out? (I guess)

So, I had already had my PATH and ANDROID_HOME set and everything, I could do `echo $PATH` and `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and it would print fine; but when I would run the different commands, it wouldn't work.

however, when I run `sudo -s` and then the commands, it works fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

ANDROID_HOME must be set to Android/Sdk folder. In my case (Ubuntu) it is:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/***<user name>***/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Put this lines at the end of ~/.profile:

```
$ gedit ~/.profile
```

Then `$ source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (and now I am stuck to Android target), but to solve Android SDK,

- go to Android studio and ensure you remove everything from Android 6,
- then that you have Android 5.1.1 installed (with v22 of the platform),
- restart your console (I had to restart the laptop)

  and normally it doesnt appear again (btw you dont need to use sudo normally)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that since you're using SUDO - that the PATH / ANDROID_HOME are not present in the root user's session. So try either:

sudo -s
export PATH=...
export ANDROID_HOME=...
meteor ...

or avoid using sudo.